# Illustrator: is there a way to toggle snapping while moving anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, technique, snapping

#### Situation

*While* moving anchor points around and…

- you currently have *Snap to Point* and *Smart Guides* turned on and
- you *momentarily* don’t want the points to snap during this operation.

#### Problem

- You have to exit what you’re doing (moving points) and
- your only choice is to visit *View* and deselect the particular snapping modes (or alternatively hit their keyboard shortcuts)

which is fairly disruptive.

#### Question

Is there a way around this?

Any solution would do; workaround, plugin, custom hack… that let's you toggle snapping on and off *while* you’re moving points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no. There is no way to disable snapping without physically choosing the menu items.

Good feature request though. It should be like Photoshop... Control/right-click to temporarily disable snap.

Comment: Ok :( Marking this as answered. Speculatively, though, if there ever pops up any 3rd party plugin or "doohickey" that makes it possible, would it be possible to switch the "Answered" mark to a new answer that includes such solution?

Comment: Yes you can change what you mark answered if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Hold <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to disable smart guides, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> to disable *snap to point.*